# Simplifying this DAX with a function or a loop?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a very lengthy code that builds a calculated table of unpivoted data (the other table has calculated fields, so I can't unpivot it through M.) Is there a way to remove all the duplicate code from my DAX? The code is consistent, with the exception of two spots, where I need to plug in a unique value. For example in the first part of SELECTCOLUMNS, the only unique value is ATL, in the second it's Austin.

```
UNION(
    FILTER(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            MetroSalesData_Table,
            "LOCATION", "ATL",
            "ZIP", MetroSalesData_Table[Zip],
            "COVERAGE", MetroSalesData_Table[_ATL],
            "CUSTOMER", MetroSalesData_Table[Customer Name],
            "TRADE (BROAD)", MetroSalesData_Table[Miner Trade Broad],
            "TRADE (GROUP)", MetroSalesData_Table[Miner Trade Group],
            "TRADE (TYPE)", MetroSalesData_Table[Miner Trade Type],
            "TRADE (METRO)", MetroSalesData_Table[Trade],
            "COGS", MetroSalesData_Table[COGS],
            "SALES", MetroSalesData_Table[Revenue]
        ), [COVERAGE] = "Area coverage only" || [COVERAGE] = "YES"
    ),
    FILTER(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            MetroSalesData_Table,
            "LOCATION", "Austin",
            "ZIP", MetroSalesData_Table[Zip],
            "COVERAGE", MetroSalesData_Table[_Austin],
            "CUSTOMER", MetroSalesData_Table[Customer Name],
            "TRADE (BROAD)", MetroSalesData_Table[Miner Trade Broad],
            "TRADE (GROUP)", MetroSalesData_Table[Miner Trade Group],
            "TRADE (TYPE)", MetroSalesData_Table[Miner Trade Type],
            "TRADE (METRO)", MetroSalesData_Table[Trade],
            "COGS", MetroSalesData_Table[COGS],
            "SALES", MetroSalesData_Table[Revenue]
        ), [COVERAGE] = "Area coverage only" || [COVERAGE] = "YES"
    ),
    FILTER(...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `MetroSalesData_Table` has a unique index column, then you can use an approach like this (I will use the name `MetroSales` below to save space):

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
        UNION(SELECTCOLUMNS(MetroSales,
                            "LOCATION", "ATL",
                            "COVERAGE", MetroSales[_ATL],
                            "Index", MetroSales[Index]),
              SELECTCOLUMNS(MetroSales,
                            "LOCATION", "Austin",
                            "COVERAGE", MetroSales[_Austin],
                            "Index", MetroSales[Index]),
              SELECTCOLUMNS([...])),
        [COVERAGE] = "Area coverage only" || [COVERAGE] = "YES"),
    "ZIP", LOOKUPVALUE(MetroSales[Zip], MetroSales[Index], [Index]),
    "CUSTOMER", LOOKUPVALUE(MetroSales[Customer Name], MetroSales[Index], [Index]),
    [...]
    "SALES", LOOKUPVALUE(MetroSales[Revenue], MetroSales[Index], [Index]))
```

Basically, we unpivot with the `UNION`, add the filter, and then add the other columns on by looking them up in the original table using the index.

If your original table doesn't have a unique index, then you can add one in the Query Editor (recommended) using **Add Column > Index Column** or else write a calculated column along the lines of the following:

```
Index = RANKX(ALL(MetroSales),
              MetroSales[Customer Name] & MetroSales[Zip],
              , ASC, Dense)
```

(Add more column names as needed to the middle line of the above if the name and zip combo isn't unique in your table.)